# Как сделать свойство объекта по умолчанию в Python при присвоении как в VBA?

Tags: vba, python-3.8

В VBA я использую свойство объекта, помеченного специальным атрибутом так, что при присвоении переменной объекта и чтении из нее я на самом деле обращаюсь к свойству этого объекта. Если у меня есть свойство объекта А.Б, то А = 1 присвоит значение 1 свойству А.Б. Возможно ли такое в Python?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: См. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10931993/10138734

Comment: Допустим, мне нужно вычислить А = Б + В (операции могут быть произвольные), где А, Б и В - объекты одного класса с множеством свойств и методов. Я хочу, чтобы в выражении выше были прочитаны значения из свойства Value объектов Б и В, были сложены в новое значение, которое было бы присвоено свойству Value объекта А. При обращении к другим свойствам и методам, запись ожидается как обычно через точку.

Comment: Присвоение A = 1 заменит значение в переменной A. Если там раньше был какой-то объект, то после присвоения будет 1. Изменить это нельзя.

Comment: Жаль. Я имею дело с сотнями формул. Обращение через точку плохо влияет на наглядность, а использование таких объектов в VBA со свойствами по умолчанию (кажущимися переменными базовых типов) помогало мне проверять значения перед присвоением, внедрять логирование, и т п., не теряя наглядность вычислений. Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Как мне дали понять на другом сайте, мне нужно увидеть это с позиции переопределения операций над объектами при помощи магических методов вроде `__add__()`. Другими словами, методы, переопределяющие ("перегружающие") арифметические операции класса объектов, как сложение `__add__()`, позволяют избавиться от явного указания свойства объекта, над которым производится операция. Например: вместо `A.value = B.value + C.value`, я могу использовать `A = B + C`.
Это решение меня устраивает.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Ответ расширен.